# Text selection code works in desktop browser doesn't work in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i have a which perfectly works in desktop but doesn't not work in mobile

**Question** : how to make it work perfectly in mobile phone also.

Here is how it works in desktop

```js
    var pageX, pageY;
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
        function copyfieldvalue() {
        var field = document.getElementById("output");
        field.focus();
        field.setSelectionRange(0, field.value.length);
        document.execCommand("copy");
        }

        let selection = document.getSelection();
        let selectedText = selection.toString();
        var menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
        if (selectedText !== "") {
        let rect = document.querySelector(".text").getBoundingClientRect();
        menu.style.display = "block";
        menu.style.left = pageX - Math.round(rect.left) + "px";
        menu.style.top = pageY - Math.round(rect.top) - 58 + "px";

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = selectedText;

        var popup = document.getElementById("mypopup");
        var copybtn = document.getElementById("copy-btn");

        copybtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            copyfieldvalue();
            popup.style.display = "block";
        });

        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-btn")[0];

        span.addEventListener("click", () => {
            popup.style.display = "none";
        });

        window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            if (event.target == popup) {
            popup.style.display = "none";
            }
        });
        } else {
        menu.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
        pageX = e.pageX;
        pageY = e.pageY;
    });
```

```css
    body {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background: #cccccc;
    }
    .text {
        width: 400px;
        min-height: 200px;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 20px 50px 50px 50px;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        line-height: 1.8;
        word-spacing: 8px;
    }
    p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    h1 {
        user-select: none;
        color: green;
    }
    .menu {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background: #a4a4a4;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    .menu i {
        color: #000;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 8px;
    }
    #output {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0.01;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .popup {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    .popup-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: 15% auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 50%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .close-btn {
        color: #aaa;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    .close-btn:hover,
    .close-btn:focus {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .popup-content p {
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Custom menu on text selection</title>
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href=
"https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
    integrity=
"sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text">
    <h1>GeeksforGeeks</h1>
    <p>
        In today’s digital world, when there are thousands of online platforms
        (maybe more than that!) available over the web, it becomes quite
        difficult for students to opt for a quality, relevant and reliable
        platform for themselves. Meanwhile, as Computer Science is a very vast
        field hence students are required to find an appropriate platform that
        can fulfill all their needs such as – Tutorials & Courses, Placement
        Preparation, Interview Experiences, and various others. And with the
        same concern, GeeksforGeeks comes in the picture – a one-stop
        destination for all Computer Science students!!
    </p>

    <div class="menu">
        <i class="fa fa-copy fa-2x" id="copy-btn"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-highlighter fa-2x" id="highlight-btn"></i>
    </div>
    <textarea id="output"></textarea>
    <div id="mypopup" class="popup">
        <div class="popup-content">
        <p>Copied!!</p>
        <span class="close-btn">×</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is a demo to try on mobile phone: https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/xxzwxxw

It works perfectly in desktop mode but does not work in mobile devices

Please help me thanks in advance !!

Comment: In general mobiles are 'touch' devices, not 'mouse' devices. Probably need to incorporate JS testing for 'touch' events.

Comment: have you tested this on an actual mobile, or just in the browsers dev tools? I know there is a problem with firefox's touch simulation: [link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1752813) but as @RenevanderLende says, you should probably / definitely incorporate touch events if you want it to be reliable on mobile